# How to put comma in large number of VennDiagram?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I have a venn diagram that I make with the package VennDiagram. The numbers are above the 100,000.[image]

I would like the number in the iddle to be 150,001, with a comma separator, or 150 000, with a small space in between. Is this possible to do with VennDiagram?

This is my example

```
library(VennDiagram)
venn.diagram(x = list(A = 1:200000,B = 50000:300000), filename = "../example.tiff")
```

Comment: This may help: `format(2000, big.mark=",")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont think you can do this easily. There are two print modes, `raw`, and `percent`, but these are hard-coded in the function (have a look at `VennDiagram::draw.triple.venn`). You can add formats by changing the function (which I wouldn't fancy)  or by manually tweaking the grobs (which is done below)

```
library(VennDiagram)
p <- venn.diagram(x = list(A = 1:200000,B = 50000:300000), filename = NULL)

# Change labels for first three text grobs
# hard-coded three, but it would be the number of text labels
# minus the number of groups passed to venn.diagram
idx <- sapply(p, function(i) grepl("text", i$name))

for(i in 1:3){
  p[idx][[i]]$label <- 
           format(as.numeric(p[idx][[i]]$label), big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)
}

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(p)
```

[image]